# Match the Creation Date of 2 sets of files with same name

Tags: command-line

I've just converted hundreds of AIF recordings from a few days ago to WAV, but I need the newly created files to keep the original Creation Date of the recordings. Filenames are identical apart from the extension, stored in two separate folders.

Is there a way to batch modify each WAV's Creation Date to match its respective AIF?

Thanks!

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16824/how-do-i-set-the-creation-time-of-a-file, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245373/batch-command-to-change-each-files-creation-date-to-match-the-information-in-th

Comment: Thanks, yes I saw this and others about `touch`, but couldn't find any that mention batch-matching another set of files' dates. Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: Basically you need to process by file, read the creation date from the AIF using `stat` and apply it to the WAV. Can write something in a few hours once I‘m in front of my Mac :-)

Comment: Are all the files in the same folder?

Comment: Oh that'd be amazing if you could! I'm a php guy that ain't too hot with unix, so your previous comment just whooshed past me. The files are currently in two separate folders, but I can place them in the same folder if it helps keep things simple.

Comment: Doesn't matter, it's just important to know how it is set up.

Comment: Just realised that I've answered nearly the same question six years ago, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57648/how-can-i-set-last-modified-date-of-file-after-using-handbrakecli-to-convert-a-f?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a folder structure like

```
./
+--AIFFolder/
+--WAVFolder/
```

and also assuming that the WAV files end in `.wav` you can use

```
cd AIFFolder
for f in *; do
    date=$(stat -f %SB -t %Y%m%d%H%M "$f")
    base=${f%.*}
    touch -t $date ../WAVFolder/"$base".wav
done
```

This can be simplified (thanks for the hint, @fd0) to

```
cd AIFFolder
for f in *; do
    touch -r "$f" ../WAVFolder/"${f%.*}.wav"
done
```

Comment: You could have just one line in your loop by using the `-r` option- `touch -r "$f" ../WAVFolder/"${f%.*}.wav"`

Comment: @fd0 I didn’t even know about that option, great stuff. Feel free to edit the code :-)